# There is issue $scope value doesn't bind to ng-model at first time load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-value

I want to display some default template in text area at very first loading.I tried to get that output but my code doesn't work.I put all breakpoints that value change.that also doesn't work. When second time data will display on text area.

```
<textarea meditor style="height: 100%;margin-top: 10px;border: 1px solid lightgray;" ng-model="activity.GoCode" name="gocode" required>{{activity.GoCode}}</textarea>

function getGoCode(data) {
    if (data.GoCode == undefined) {
           $scope.activity.GoCode = "test";
    } else {
          $scope.activity.GoCode = data.GoCode;
          };
    }
```

Comment: try to put  {{modelname}} and check your text is coming in view.

Comment: @NayasSubramanian i tried but didn't work

Comment: do you have any working model binding in current scope?

Comment: yes this code also work for second time load

Comment: not sure need to check the code.

Comment: thank for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found solution for this
I set a value initially for this variable (`activity.GoCode`) before that I create 
'`$scope.activity`' object and then assign value for when data is loaded.

```
   $scope.ReadSampleGoFile = function () {

        $http.get('settings/sampleGO.txt').then(function (data) {
            //use the file data here
            // console.log(data.data);
             $scope.activity=[];
             $scope.activity.GoCode=data.data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to declare $scope.activity as an object rather than an Array:    $scope.activity={}

Answer (score 0):

When does your function getGoCode() is called, upon page load ?

I see one issue with your code even if it is not probably the problem here, having:

```
ng-model="activity.GoCode"
```

and

```
{{activity.GoCode}}
```

is redundant as explain here and will cause an exception in Internet explorer (Error: Invalid Argument) as explain [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025#issuecomment-155711475)

Also what is the meditor directive doing, it is possible that this directive is the source of your problem as I don't see why your code would not work

Comment: Thnaks for the help i found solution.